# How can I tell if a method modifies the class?

Tags: c++

I am writing C++ code and I have a class with a number of member methods. For example, `print()` and `act()`; the former does not modify the internals of the class (i.e., the variable `i`) while the latter does.

```cpp
class Example {
    int i;

    void act() { i++; };
    void print() { };
```

This is obvious in this case, but for longer methods, or methods whose definition and declaration have been separated, it is not obvious which methods may alter the object. Is there a way of explicitly denoting that a method is non-modifying?

(As an example in another language, in C I might pass a pointer to the object. If a function is non-modifying, I would pass a constant pointer.)

Comment: You cannot. Instead, you remark member functions as `const` if you want to promise that they don't. I.e. `void print() const { }`. Non-const function may not be called for `const` objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way of explicitly denoting that a method is non-modifying?

Yes. Mark it as `const`, eg:

```cpp
void print() const;
```

This will mark the `this` pointer inside the method's body as pointing at a `const` object (ie `const Example *this`).  Any attempt to modify that object via that `this` pointer will cause a compiler error.

Comment: Thank you for the answer (and to Scheff's Cat) -- this is what I was looking for. I will accept when the timer expires.

Comment: `const` member functions CAN modify both `mutable`  members and `static` (if not marked `const`) members of the class.   They can also modify members of other non-`const` instances of the class